# Is there a known way to root the G975W (S10+ Canadian)?

Tags: samsung, rooting, root-access

I am trying to root the G975W, specifically the "Galaxy S10 Exynos (SM-G975W)" /G975WVLU2ASGJ so that I can install LineageOS (https://download.lineageos.org/beyond2lte). However, when searching for how to root this device, I find mixed results: some posts say that only specific models of the G975 can be rooted; some say that the Canadian models are impossible to root; and some indicate that a very specific exploit or service is required to do so. I bought the device second-hand, though I do have the original box and all relevant information on it. It is allegedly unlocked, and in the developer settings, there is no mention of "OEM Unlock"

*It is running on android 11 and I am able to access the "Download Custom OS" screen, along with the warning (https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Kqi.jpg).

Would anyone know if/how I would be able to put LineageOS on my device or if it is possible to root the device?

Thanks for any help/info.

Comment: depends on android version. fourth option mentioned is UNSAMLOCK

Comment: Is is on Android 11

Comment: according to your bootloader level (6) that device is not unlockable (yet). don't update ever again and wait a few months/years then get your DID and buy unlock token